# ovethrown and fire-blasted blocks = overturned and scorched?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

I would like to clarify whether my understanding is correct (a sentence from an old tale where the main character climbs up to an old, ruinous city):

> It was like climbing amid the overthrown and fire-blasted blocks of a
> titan citadel.

I struggle especially with the word "fire-blasted", but my best attempt to rephrase that would be:

> amid the overturned, scorched blocks (=large bricks, boulders?)..

Comment: Yes. _Blocks_ is probably _stones_ (i.e. carved blocks of stone).

Comment: "Overthrown" can mean simply "toppled"—not necessarily "overturned."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collins dictionary online has "If you describe something as a building block of something, you mean it is one of the separate parts that combine to make that thing." This would apply to the stones, bricks, boulders, concrete, or similar components  of the old city.

The effective adjective "fire-blasted" seems to parallel "scorched" but has connotations of surface damage similar to sand-blasted or wind-blasted, additional to the heat damage and marking.